# Swaption pricing and strategies

Tags: option-pricing, volatility, trading, swaption, exotics

I am looking for resources (books, papers, websites, etc.) that deal with Vanilla and Exotic swaptions from a more advanced and quantitative perspective. I am interested in both the pricing side (e.g. how to price mid curves, curve options, CMS, how to model correlation, etc.) and the pure trading side (e.g. managing of the risk, strategies, etc.)

Literature seems to be very wide on Equity products, but I am somehow struggling to find interesting and comprehensive materials on Rates Vol - any suggestion is very appreciated.